# Compare list of tuples against column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I'm learning pandas and I have a problem I can't solve.

I have a dataframe with around 200k rows, being one of the columns an id. It looks like this:

```
    call_id id      utterance   channel  seq    sentiment
0     uuid            str         str    str      float
```

I also have a list of tuples with this shape:

```
(id, pattern_id)
tup = [('c638b6fe-0939-4a3b-a7f0-c9b315da1e5d', '56e1542f-5d68-4fe0-a85a-cce8ae1f0b94'),...]
```

being these elements strings.

I'd like to compare the id in each row of the dataframe against the ids in the list of tuples and, if there is match, add the pattern_id of the matching tuple to a new column in the dataframe. **The length of the list of tuples is not equal to the number of rows in the dataframe.**

I've tried different methods but any of them worked fine.
It seems I'm able to make the comparison, for example:

```
matches = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    for t in tuples:
        if row.id == t[0]:
            matches.append(t[1])
```

and I get the matches I have to get. But if I add an else the comparison doesn't seem to work:

```
matches = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    for t in tuples:
        if row.id == t[0]:
            matches.append(t[1])
        else:
            matches.append("nan")
```

I would appreciate any help to understand:

- why this is not working
- how to add the result of the comparison per row to a new column in the dataframe.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a sample of the dataframe and a sample with your list of tuples.

Comment: I've added the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a dataframe out of list of tuples, like this:
`df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples, columns =['id', 'pattern_id'])`
and then join it with the main dataframe, like this:
`joined = main_df.merge(df, on='id', how='inner')`. The `pattern_id` is included in `joined` for rows having matched `id`.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I was wondering if it is a way to merge the two dataframes in a way that the resulting df includes all the rows, having or not having a match? And pattern_id being something like "N/A" if there is not match. Is this possible?

Comment: Then you can change `how` keyword argument. `how='left'` will give you all rows of main_df. It works like SQL joins.